# DynamoDB Datamapper error throws item did not adhere to the DynamoDBTable protocol

Tags: node.js, angular

Not really sure where my error is here, Im using the AWS DynamoDb mapper function in node.js but I get this error:

**The provided item did not adhere to the DynamoDbTable protocol. No 
string property was found at the `DynamoDbTable` symbol**
I followed the tutorial they provide, I made some changes so I can use cjs but can't seem to find the issue.

```js
const {
  DynamoDBSchema,
  DynamoDBTable,
  embed
} = require("@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper");
const v4 = require("uuid/v4");
class Invoice {}

Object.defineProperties(Invoice.prototype, {
  DynamoDBTable: {
    value: 'invoices'
  },
  [DynamoDBSchema]: {
    value: {
      id: {
        type: "String",
        keyType: "HASH",
        defaultProvier: v4
      },

      invoiceId: {type:'String'},
      firstname:{type:'String'},
      lastname:{type:'String'},
      email:{type:'String'},
      items:{type:'List',memberType:{type:'Map'}},
      tax:{type:'String'},
      total:{type:'String'},
      paymentStatus:{type:'String'},
      paymentType:{type:'String'},
      paymentInfo:{type:'List',memberType:{type:'Map'}}

    }
    
  }
});
   module.exports = Invoice;
```

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const {DataMapper} = require('@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper');
const Invoice= require('../models/invoices.model');

const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  region: "us-east-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:1948"
});
const ddbDoc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
  region: "us-east-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:1948"
})

const mapper = new DataMapper({
  client: new AWS.DynamoDB({region: "us-east-1",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:1948"})
})

let data = new Invoice();


//mapper.put({data}).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
async function getItems(){
  for await( const foo of mapper.scan(data,{indexName:'Invoiceid-Email'}) ){
    console.log(foo)
  }
}
getItems().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Typescript, you have to `new` up the model.

```
@table('myTable')
export class MyModel {
  constructor(model?: Partial<MyModel>) {
    if (model) {
      Object.assign(this, model);
    }
  }

  @hashKey()
  pk: string;

  name: string;
}

// This won't work
const wontWork: MyModel = { pk: 'Cust#1', name: 'John' };

// You have to do this
const willWork = new MyModel();
willWork.pk = 'Cust#1';
willWork.name = 'John';

// This will also work
const willAlsoWork = new MyModel({ pk: 'Cust#1', name: 'John' });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put `DynamoDBTable` inside square brackets similar to `DynamoDBSchema`.

Comment: Note to anyone googling this: You will also get the same error if you pass an undefined table name when using the @table(tableName) decorator. That can accidentally happen when you pass an environment variable that's not defined in the Lambda function. So make sure that the table name is defined properly.

Comment: I had the same issue `The provided item did not adhere to the DynamoDbTable protocol.` when i was creating DynamoDB Document via `const obj = { ...properties } as MyDynamoDocument;`

The sollution for me was to use `const obj = new MyDynamoDocument();` and then set all properties as `obj.property1 = property1;`